# localization of completion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(R,m)$ be a local Noetherian [excellent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excellent_ring) domain and $\hat R$ be the $m$-adic completion of $R.$ Let $0\neq c\in R$ and $R_c$ is regular.

How to show that **${\hat R}_c$ is also  regular?**

Comment: Hint: try to show localization commutes with completion at a maximal ideal.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Note that $R_c$ is not necessarily local if $\dim R > 1$.

Comment: I have edited my question and change the ring to excellent ring. This is required in the proof of existence of test element in characteristic p method